# How do I make a mill plants work order tied to the amount of dye?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

How do I make a mill plants work order tied to the amount of dye?

E.g., a mill plants work order on a quern that activates only when the amount of dimple dye drops below 10.

I'm using the DFHack workshop profile function.  One combination that does *not* work is:

- item type : powder
- material : dimple cup dye
- traits: Dye items

The phrase on the screen after setting these conditions is "*Amount of dye dimple dye available is less than 10. Satisfied for next check*" even though I have hundreds of units of dimple dye in a few dozen bags.

Answer (score 1):

I use following steps to automate the textile industy:

1. Mill 5 plants when amount of "dye boxes and bags" (item: boxes and bags; trait: dye items) is at most 10.

Be sure to use to use a stockpile without barrels for the dyes.

This works well. Combine it with

2. process 5 plants when amount of pig tail thread(item: thread; material: pig tail) is at most 30
3. weave 5 thread to cloth when amount of pigtail cloth(item: cloth; material: pig tail) is at most 30
4. dye 5 cloth when amount of dyable cloth (item: cloth; trait: dyable item) is at least 10

Be sure to use a stockpile without bins for the cloths.

The final step is something like:

5. limited production: make 5 cloth shoes when amount of pig tail shoes (item: shoe; material: pig tail) is at most 30
6. mass production: make 5 cloth robe when amount of dyed cloth (item: cloth; trait: dyed item) is at least 5

Comment: The same trick can be used for automating the glass industry (assuming you have magma): collect 5 sand when amount of sand-bearing items is at most 8 (item: boxes and bags; trait: sand-bearing). be sure to have a bin-less sandbag stockpile nearby (furniture stockpile -> sandbags).

Comment: The settings assumes that the work orders (o-W) are "auto-loom off" and "only use dyed cloth".